# reducer not getting called even action get callled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I try to add more props to existing list i am able to fire dispatch action but reducer doesn't get trigger
i have my headercontainer.js file like

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { fetchAccount } from 'actions/account'
    import { getAccount } from 'reducers/account'
    import { fetchCart } from 'actions/cart'
    import { getCart } from 'reducers/cart'
    //import * as cls from 'actions/cls'
    import { getReadmore } from 'reducers/cls'
    import * as cls from 'actions/cls'

    import { fetchAuthenticityToken } from 'actions/authenticityToken'
    import { getAuthenticityToken } from 'reducers/authenticityToken'
    import Header from 'components/Header'

    class HeaderContainer extends Component {
      static propTypes = {
        account: PropTypes.object,
        authenticityToken: PropTypes.object,
        cart: PropTypes.object,
          dispatch: PropTypes.func

      }

      componentDidMount() {
        if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
          if (!this.props.account.isFetching) {
            this.props.dispatch(fetchAccount())
          }
          if (!this.props.authenticityToken.isFetching) {
            this.props.dispatch(fetchAuthenticityToken())
          }
          if (!this.props.cart.isFetching) {
            this.props.dispatch(fetchCart())
          }
        }
      }

       constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {classToSend: true };
        }

        stateToRender(){
            (this.state.classToSend) ? this.setState({classToSend: false}) : this.setState({classToSend: true});
        }




        onClickHandler(){

            this.stateToRender();
            let action = cls.readMore(this.state.classToSend)
        this.props.dispatch(action)



            // this.props.readMore(this.state.classToSend);
        }


      render() {
        const { account, cart, authenticityToken } = this.props

        if(!account || !cart) {
          return false
        }

        return (
            <div id ="cvb">
          <div id="toggle-nav" className={this.state.toggleClass?'visible-xs nav-open':'visible-xs'} onClick={() => this.onClickHandler()} >
          <span data-action="toggle-nav" className="action mt-menu-label">
            <span className="mt-menu-bread mt-menu-bread-top">
              <span className="mt-menu-bread-crust mt-menu-bread-crust-top"></span>
            </span>
            <span className="mt-menu-bread mt-menu-bread-middle">
              <span className="mt-menu-bread-crust mt-menu-bread-crust-middle"></span>
            </span>
            <span className="mt-menu-bread mt-menu-bread-bottom">
              <span className="mt-menu-bread-crust mt-menu-bread-crust-bottom"></span>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div> 

          <Header account={account} cart={cart} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        account: getAccount(state),
        cart: getCart(state),
        classToSend: getReadmore(state),
        authenticityToken: getAuthenticityToken(state)
      }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HeaderContainer)
```

> My cls.js  reducer

```
export function getReadmore(state) {
console.log(state.readMore1)
console.log("are yar")
return state.readMore1
}

export  function readMore1 (state="", action) {
console.log(action.type)
 switch(action.type){

    case READ_MORE:

        return action.payload;
}

return state;
}
```

> cls.js Action

```
export function readMore(class_something) {


const READ_MORE = 'READ_MORE';

    console.log("--------------------------")
    console.log(class_something)

    return {
        type: READ_MORE,
        payload: class_something
    };

}
```

Though i am able to call action cls.js file but reducer not getting trigger 
can anyone help me to get out of this trouble.

My edits

my index.js in reducer folder

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import { currency } from './currency'
import { cart } from './cart'
import { account } from './account'
import { alerts } from './alerts'
import { login } from './login'
import { authenticityToken } from './authenticityToken'
import { products } from './products'
import { product } from './product'

const routing = routerReducer

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form,
  routing,
  currency,
  cart,
  cls,
  account,
  alerts,
  authenticityToken,
  login,
  products,
  product
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: Do you get any js developer console errors ?

Comment: @elpddev No errors

Comment: It should because as @D Vorona answer the `case READ_MORE:` is not defined. Where do you set the `READ_MODE` in the reducer for it to know what its mean ? Do you import it ?

Comment: in cls.js action i define it

Answer (score 0):

Your case in your reducer file should be "READ_MORE" (with quotations) not READ_MORE (without quotations).

Comment: No thats not an issue

Comment: Okay. Where do you instantiate your store? Have you linked it to your reducers?

Comment: Action not called reducer

Comment: Okay, the primary concept of redux is a sort of parent state container that is always overwritten, and never directly modified. Actions are dispatched to signal a change of your app's state, and the reducer is the function that translates this into a state change, as you've coded in your excerpts above. What you're missing (unless you simply haven't included the file) is your store, which is this parent state container.

Comment: Look at redux's [example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html). You're very close, you just need to create your store and link your reducers so they have something to change.

Comment: If you have multiple reducer files, you create a rootReducer.js file, import your reducers into it, and then use combineReducer() to combine them. Then you need to import this rootReducer file into your store.js file, which is where you create your store (with the function createStore()).

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is import that index.js file into the file where you create your store. Also, as @elpddev mentioned, unless you specifically import READ_MORE into that reducer file, it's undefined. The convention is to just use the string "READ_MORE".

Comment: i put import { readMore1 } from './cls'
in index.js of reducers   andput cls in combinereducer too but now showing  undefined cls